# Compiling/Debugging LZMA

Tags: c++, lzma

I need to compile the C++ implementation of LZMA (7Z). Does anybody know how to do that? where should I download it from?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Get [LZMA SDK](http://7-zip.org/sdk.html), read **lzma.txt** and take a look at **LzmaUtil.c** if you don't like C there is some C++ sources there too.